# SQS to AWS Lambda Function with AWS Chalice and BOTO3

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

- I am using AWS SQS to store information coming in from an external server and then sending it to a Lambda function to process it and dequeue the information.
- The information that I am sending in is in the form of a JSON and is being used as a python dictionary.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    for record in event['Records']:
        messageHandler(record)

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Batch Processed')
}
```

- Assuming that the code for the messageHandler is working and properly implemented, how do I catch the messages from the queue in their batches. This is all being deployed by AWS Chalice without the use of CLI.

I am well out of my depth right now and have no idea why this is not working when I deploy it but is working when I trigger a normal Lambda Function in the AWS Console through the SQS Send/Recieve Message feature. As far as I know the triggers are set up correctly and they should have no issue.

If you have any questions please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The event that you are processing will look something like this:

```json
{
    "Records": [
        {
            "messageId": "11d6ee51-4cc7-4302-9e22-7cd8afdaadf5",
            "receiptHandle": "AQEBBX8nesZEXmkhsmZeyIE8iQAMig7qw...",
            "body": "Test message.",
            "attributes": {
                "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
                "SentTimestamp": "1573251510774",
                "SequenceNumber": "18849496460467696128",
                "MessageGroupId": "1",
                "SenderId": "AIDAIO23YVJENQZJOL4VO",
                "MessageDeduplicationId": "1",
                "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1573251510774"
            },
            "messageAttributes": {},
            "md5OfBody": "e4e68fb7bd0e697a0ae8f1bb342846b3",
            "eventSource": "aws:sqs",
            "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-2:123456789012:fifo.fifo",
            "awsRegion": "us-east-2"
        }
    ]
}
```

where the `"body"` is your json encoded message. You'll want your message handler function to do something like this:

```py
def message_handler(event):
    message = json.loads(event["body"])
    # do stuff...
```

The return value from the lambda is pretty pointless if it is being used as the event target from sqs.

Comment: Thank you, I will have to try this, I have moved from SQS to a different area of the project but will likely revisit that section soon at which point in time I will attempt to implement this.